# Java: Currency symbol based on ISO 4217 currency cod

Tags: java

Below program prints the Currency symbol given the ISO 4217 currency code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Currency{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Currency myInstance = Currency.getInstance(args[0]);
        System.out.println(myInstance.getSymbol());
    }
}
```

**Problem**: Works fine when the string USD is input. For other inputs like EUR just return the Currency Code.

Sample input , ouput from the program:

```
input: java Currency USD 
output: $
input: java Currency EUR
output: EUR -> I expect the symbol of Euro here
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`Currency.getSymbol()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol%28%29) returns the currency symbol relative to the default locale.

> Gets the symbol of this currency for the default locale. For example, for the US Dollar, the symbol is `"$"` if the default locale is the US, while for other locales it may be `"US$"`. If no symbol can be determined, the ISO 4217 currency code is returned.

Use [`Currency.getSymbol(Locale locale)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getSymbol%28java.util.Locale%29) if you want the symbol for a different locale.

```
System.out.println(
   Currency.getInstance("USD").getSymbol(Locale.US)
);
// prints $

System.out.println(
   Currency.getInstance("USD").getSymbol(Locale.FRANCE)
);
// prints USD

System.out.println(
   Currency.getInstance("EUR").getSymbol(Locale.US)
);
// prints EUR

System.out.println(
   Currency.getInstance("EUR").getSymbol(Locale.FRANCE)
);
// prints €
```

([see also on ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/Dwau9)).

Comment: @polygenelubricats: The above works when we also know the locale country. I currently only have the ISO 4217 currency cod and nothing else. I need to figure out the locale from the currency code and then the implementation would be similar to above code.

Comment: @polygenelubricats: Yeah very similar , but instead of printing Locale , I just need the symbol of currency in that local. But this approach helps thanks.

Comment: The problem with the default Java implementation is that it's just dumb. For example, if I'm displaying euros in the US locale, I should see something like €75, not EUR75 - everyone in the US knows what the actual euro symbol is much better than "EUR". Thus, I always have to use custom code, like setting DecimalFormatSymbols manually, to get decent looking output instead of being able to depend on the stock implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For me, your code even in the first case returns USD. It seemes, that Currency heavily depends on the JRE version (1.6 for me). Perosnally I recommend you to write your own CUR to symbol conversion module - it will be much easier, than try to use this one.

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs it the other way round (for example € -> EUR)

```
String currency = €;
String currencyCode = "";
for (Currency c : Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()) {
    if (c.getSymbol().equals(currency)) {
        currencyCode = c.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: i was searching exactly this, thanks!!!

Comment: unfortunately, this only works for typical currency symbols like €, £ or $ but for other currencies like Лв (Bulgarian Lev) it doens't

Answer (score -1):

Using the limited Locale enum's only caters for westernised symbols.  If you want to be a little more global try using Locales provided by:

```
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

Using Locales from this list gave symbols rather than TLA's pretty consistently.

Comment: It doesn't work. It still gives only $ symbol for all others it gives currency codes only e.g. EUR.