# icu4j returns currency code instead of symbol

Tags: java, android, localization, formatting, icu4j

**Background**

I have an Android application where I want to format an integer value as a currency string depending on the ISO code and current locale. I'm using ICU library 1.8.1 for that.

For example, if I have a value 75 and the ISO code is "USD", I want to see "$75" on US locale, but "USD75" on French locale.

**Problem**

The problem is that I always see "USD75" even when I explicitly set the locale to US. I thought the problem is in my `NumberFormat` currency instance, but then I tried to simply get the currency symbol and noticed that it's incorrect. For some reason `getSymbol()` method always returns currency code.

```
public void test() {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    String theISOCode = "USD"
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(theISOCode);

    currency.getCurrencyCode(); // "USD". This works as expected
    currency.getSymbol(); // "USD". This looks weird.. Shouldn't it be "$"?
    currency.getSymbol(Locale.US); // "USD". Same here, I expect it to be "$"
    currency.getSymbol(ULocale.US); // still "USD"
}
```

I also checked this link: [Java: Currency symbol based on ISO 4217 currency cod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994016/java-currency-symbol-based-on-iso-4217-currency-cod). It seems my app works a bit differently. Not sure if it's a bug in the library.

**Question**

It makes sense to me that `currency.getSymbol()` returns "USD" if your locale is `Locale.FRANCE`. But why does it return "USD" when my locale is `Locale.US`? Would be great if I could find a solution without switching the library.

Comment: I ran the code and it gives me "USD" on `currency.getCurrencyCode();` but on other three I get "$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a bug in the library. After updating the version the issue got resolved. Thanks @Omid for looking into this.